# Minitest Exit on first failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm using Minitest with Rails.

How do I get it to exit on the first failure if I'm running a bunch of tests? I want this to happen when I'm writing the tests because it's a waste of time for later tests to run after the failed one.

Comment: You can just target specific tests? So if you got a red one you can just run that specific test until it's green?

Comment: @vgoff I'm running Rails 4.1.6. I saw that RSpec has a `fail_fast` option, so I'm basically wondering if there's a similar option for `Test::Unit`.

Comment: When you say Test::Unit, unsure which library you are using.  Do you mean minitest?  I guess at the moment, the Ruby version would be helpful as well, as now you really aren't talking about Rails so much as Ruby and a library.

Comment: @vgoff Ah, it's actually Minitest. I'll change it in the question. Also, I'm running ruby 2.1.2p95.

Comment: [minitest-fail-fast](https://github.com/teoljungberg/minitest-fail-fast) gem?

Answer (score 5):

I've just found this answer while searching for the solution, but at least in Rails 5.1 you have one option:

```
rails test -h Usage: bin/rails test [options] [files or directories]

You can run a single test by appending a line number to a filename:

    bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:27

You can run multiple files and directories at the same time:

    bin/rails test test/controllers test/integration/login_test.rb

By default test failures and errors are reported inline during a run.

Rails options:
    -w, --warnings                   Run with Ruby warnings enabled
    -e, --environment                Run tests in the ENV environment
    -b, --backtrace                  Show the complete backtrace
    -d, --defer-output               Output test failures and errors after the test run
    -f, --fail-fast                  Abort test run on first failure or error
    -c, --[no-]color                 Enable color in the output
```

So you just just need to run `rails test -f`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [minitest-fail-fast](https://github.com/teoljungberg/minitest-fail-fast) gem.  You may also modify the Minitest reporters engine to `exit` after reporting a failure.